# How to set Global Custom Font in App.xaml

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a custom font in my assets folder and need to assign this font as the global font for the app. This is what I thought of but it's not working.

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MetricWebRegular">
                ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/MetricWeb-Regular.ttf#Metric Web
</FontFamily>
```

I'm calling this by adding it to a style setter in a textbox.

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a way to set up global custom font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is what I thought of but it's not working.

It's hard to know what is going wrong here, just base on your code, it should work. Firstly, I don't have your font resource, I downloaded one from Internet and tested like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="MetricWebRegular">ms-appx:///Assets/Blambot-Custom.ttf#Blambot Custom</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources>
```

then use this resource in the style setter in a textbox:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        ...
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MetricWebRegular}" />    
        ...

          </Setter>
      </Style>
  </Page.Resources>
```

And my `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="Hello 11111222333" FontSize="30" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
```

It works perfectly:

[image]

Here is my font [download Uri](http://www.abstractfonts.com/download/1297?option=installer). I downloaded it and changed its name here so it will meet the format as yours.

So,

1. Make sure your font file has no problem.
2. `ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/MetricWeb-Regular.ttf#Metric Web` this path means your font file is under the `Fonts` folder of the `Assets` folder, make sure the path is right.
3. If you want to use this resource, you need to use `StaticResource` and its key.
4. If you want to override the default font family, you can override the `ContentControlThemeFontFamily` resource like this:

`<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">ms-appx:///Assets/Blambot-Custom.ttf#Blambot Custom</FontFamily>`, the result of my layout is here:

[image]

If there is still problem, you can leave a comment to post the download url of your font file resource, so can we download it and have a test.

Comment: Its working now :D I placed the Fonts in the assets folder of the PCL hahaha. Thanks for a thorough explanation though :))